# Dropwizard binding field names in custom Error messages

Tags: java, api, dropwizard

How do I bind the field name of an incoming request to a suitable error message in the following format.  `field1` should refer to the contents of `@JsonProperty("field1")`, instead it is bound to a Path which has the following format `Resource.method.arg0.field1`

Expected Output

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "field1",
      "message": "error message"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following ConstraintExceptionMapper but this looks like the wrong approach. Are there any suitable alternatives that allows me to keep using javax validations but bind the values of a `@QueryParam("productCode")` to a custom error object.

```
    public class CustomConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JerseyViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JerseyViolationException exception) {
        List<ValidationError> validationErrors = constraintViolationToValidationErrors(exception);
        final Invocable invocable = exception.getInvocable();
        final int status = determineStatus(exception.getConstraintViolations(), invocable);
        List<Error> errors =
                validationErrors.stream()
                        .map((e) -> new Error(e.getPath(), e.getMessage()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Response.status(status).entity(new Errors(errors)).build();
    }

    private String getFieldName(String path) {
        return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length());
    }

}
```

Request Object

```
public class RequestObject {

    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty(message = "field1 is a required parameter")
    private final String field1;

    @JsonCreator
    public FutureTradeDateParams(@QueryParam("field1") String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    @JsonProperty("field1")
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

}
```